# javascript extract ..stop at the first underscore in the value

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to extract hostname-rt45 from hostname-rt45_34_we_35. I am using /(.*)_?.*/g. This doesn't seem to work. I have reviewed the regex documentation. Thought using the ? would make it greedy and stop at the first underscore. What am I missing?

at https://regexr.com/, I have tried.

```
/(.*)_?.*/g
/(.*)_.*/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for a sequence of non `_` characters that have an underscore after them (positive lookahead) - ([RegExr example](http://regexr.com/4ogv8)):

```js
const regex = /[^_]+(?=_)/;
const str = 'hostname-rt45_34_we_35';

const [result] = str.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution without regex:

```
var host = 'hostname-rt45_34_we_35';
console.log(host.substring(0,host.indexOf('_')));
```

`indexOf()` returns the index of the first underscore found.

Answer (score 0):

`^[^_]+` might work OK.

```js
const regex = /^[^_]+/g;
const str = `hostname-rt45_34_we_35
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(match);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/imcVWC/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/imcVWC/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]